# XCode -- what does working copy mean, anyway?

Tags: xcode, git

When you forget to check the 'initialize git repository' box in XCode, you can still use git VC by selecting 'create working copy' from the Source Control menu bar item.

I'm confused about this term; is working copy another name for a git repository? Elsewhere I've seen the term 'working copy' defined as 'an in-memory representation of the compilation unit on disk' ([jetbrains](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_working_copy%3F))

Is this how git repositories work? I didn't think they created copies of any code. Is this route to initializing the repository different than running git init, or checking the initialize git repository checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "working copy" means different things in different contexts.

For Git, "working copy" is a directory full of files with a `.git` subdirectory. It's the same as a local git repository.

For Jetbrains/Eclipse, the "working copy" is a Java-specific thing for in-memory compilation. It doesn't have anything to do with Git.

Comment: ahh ok thanks!! Sounds like there is no difference between the 3 methods I outlined above -- they all just create a .git subdirectory